# Angular IDE not installing on Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring-tool-suite, angular-ide

For last two days, I am trying to install the Angular IDE for Angular 5 by simply following [this](http://javasampleapproach.com/tool/setup-angular-ide-spring-tool-suite) tutorial, but after taking too long time for downloading it gives error on **STS Version: 3.8.3.RELEASE, Build Id: 201612191351, Platform: Eclipse Neon.2 on Windows 7**

After around 2 hours it says that Installation cannot be completed as requested

[image: Second dialog box]

And then after clicking **confirm** it shows the below error.

[image]

Also, when I look into the **progress** bar it tries to reach some url continuously like

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-ide/content.jar   https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/content.xml.xz https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/content.xml https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/artifacts.xml

And when I manually tried to open the URLs then I got **404 URL not found error** for all of them except the first one which is of angular-ide/content.jar.

I tried googling for the solution and the results having tutorials or steps to install the Angular IDE only.

Am i missing any configuration setting or something else? Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use "Vistual studio code" for implementing angular 5  and you can integrate java back end which is implemented in STS with angular 5 easily.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @rajaskhar. Is "Visual studio code" have all of the features which STS have and which are required for Java and spring boot, maven development along with Angular 5? Actually all of my projects are being developed using STS only.

Comment: I am also working on Angular 5 and java spring boot with maven actually.. I am using Visual studio which is one of the best editor for angular and using STS for spring boot. We can implement java with Visual studio but I am not sure how much it is user friendly like STS

Comment: Yeah, i.e. the reason am trying to use Angular IDE within STS to avoid using two separate IDEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that shows up in the popup indicates that a network issue happened while accessing the p2 repository of the Angular IDE marketplace entry. To resolve that, I would recommend to go to the `Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Update Sites`, select the one for Angular, remove that, and restart STS. This wipes out stale cache data and might remain in your install and cause issues if there was a network glitch in the past. Then try again.

I also checked the install via the Eclipse Marketplace on STS 3.9.4 (on Eclipse 4.7.3a) as well as STS 3.8.4 (on Eclipse 4.7.0), and it both seemed to work just fine, so it looks like there isn't a fundamental compatibility problem (at least not with those two versions).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your approach as well and trying to install the Angular IDE again and it was looking to be easy as it started the installation. But soon reaching the half way I got another error like `session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://downloads.genuitec.com/downloads/products/webclipse/updates/wc2017ci11b3/plugins/com.genuitec.eclipse.typescript_2.5.3.201804262329.jar.
Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 26560295; received: 8936220`

Comment: After trying 3rd time while repeating the steps you suggested, the Angular IDE has now been installed.

Answer (score 0):

Of possible interest, please see: https://grokonez.com/tool/setup-angular-ide-spring-tool-suite

The version of STS I have is:

Spring Tool Suite

Version: 3.9.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201712210947
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)

Copyright (c) 2007 - 2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
All rights reserved. Visit http://spring.io/tools/sts